# Tomcat: How to access a local file within an Apache CXF-webapp?

Tags: tomcat, cxf

I have a tomcat running my [CXF-based](http://cxf.apache.org/) webapp.

Methods I work with have signatures like that:

```
@GET
@Path ("/handler/contract/{ItemId}")
@Produces ("application/xml")
public Item getItem(@PathParam("ItemId") Integer ItemId) throws Exception{  
    //...
    return item;
}
```

This is usually very useful since I don't have to deal with reponse/request objects and cover the business logic.

But now I need to access a local file in order to insert it into a PDF. I looked at all items here and in the doc but couldn't find a reliable, **easy** way to access the *Context* or *Request* to find the current path of the webapp so I can access the file within the exploded WAR.

Any help how to get the current local path of the CXF-webapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, if you finally wrote a post you'll find the solution yourself. With the `@Context` annotation you'll get the correct context.

```
@GET
@Path ("/handler/contract/{ItemId}")
@Produces ("application/xml")
public Item getItem(@Context ServletContext context, @PathParam("ItemId") Integer ItemId) throws Exception{  
    //retrieve the local path from the context
    String currentLocalPath = context.getRealPath(".");
    //...
    return item;
}
```

Thanks for visiting. :)